# In Thunar, how are bookmarked folders hashed to create the accelerator shortcut in accels.scm?

Tags: xubuntu, shortcut-keys, xfce, thunar, hash

Thunar's `accels.scm` file contains hashed values for each of my bookmarked folders. For instance, let's say I have the following folder bookmarked:

`/home/<username>/Personal/`

If I open up the `accels.scm` file, I would then see a line that looks like this:

`(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarBookmarks/89074f17cc2cbef71b1eeb472f0fda88" "")`

where `89074f17cc2cbef71b1eeb472f0fda88` is, I'm assuming, the hashed value of `/home/<username>/Personal/`. This leads me to two questions:

First, how is `/home/<username>/Personal/` turned into `89074f17cc2cbef71b1eeb472f0fda88`? Any idea what hash function is used?

Second, in the `gtk_accel_path`, I can put a keyboard shortcut in the second set of quotation marks, and when I use that shortcut, Thunar will open that folder. But the shortcut is associated with the hashed path. How does Thunar know that `89074f17cc2cbef71b1eeb472f0fda88` corresponds to `/home/<username>/Personal/`? I can't find any file that associates these two values. Since you can't un-hash a hashed value, I imagine such a file would be necessary to figure out the original path behind the hashed value.

Answer (score 0):

So after further research, I answered my first question and figured out the hash values are simple md5s. For instance, `89074f17cc2cbef71b1eeb472f0fda88` is just the md5 hash of `file:///home/<username>/Personal`.

However, I'm still curious as to the second question. I have a sneaking suspicion that when loaded, Thunar hashes each of the bookmarked file paths and stores the hashed and un-hashed values together in some kind of internal dictionary or hash table. If somebody could confirm this, though, that would be a big help.